# Drawing a circle with a specific start point (from degree view)

Tags: geometry, drawing

the drawing algorithm which I currently use:

```
a_max =  Pi*2 (float)(num_segments - 1.0f)/(float)num_segments; 
for (unsigned int i = 0; i<=num_segments;i++)
{
const float a = (float)i / (float)num_segments * a_max;
SetPixel(centre.x + cos(a) *radius, centre.y +sin(a) *radius); 
}
```

Works fine, but it starts drawing at (centre.x+radius, centre.y). I would like to have it to start at the top , because I want to draw a compass and zero degree is at the top, not on the right, so that I don't have to make a hacky solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try rotating 90 degrees to the left before you start drawing, this should solve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

A compass not only starts at "north" instead of "east" but also goes clockwise instead of counter-clockwise.

For this case, just swap `sin(a)` and `cos(a)`:

```
x = centre.x + sin(a) * radius
y = centre.y + cos(a) * radius
```